# Аргумент в сообщении

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, api

Как это реализовать?

```
'Тики, переверни (предложение)' => utf8_strevv("предложение")
```

Нужно как-нибудь взять предложение после слова "переверни" и внести его в utf8_strrev()

Код:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_REQUEST)) {
    return;
}
$confirmationToken = 'скрыл';
$token = 'скрыл';
$secretKey = 'скрыл';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
if(strcmp($data->secret, $secretKey) !== 0 && strcmp($data->type, 'confirmation') !== 0)
    return;


switch ($data->type) {
    case 'confirmation':
        echo $confirmationToken;
        break;

    case 'message_new':
        $user_id = $data->object->from_id;
        $user_info = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids={$user_id}&access_token=$token&v=5.80"));
        $user_name = $user_info->response[0]->first_name;
        $message = $data->object->text;
        $url = 'https://vk.com/foaf.php?id='.$user_id;
        $file = file_get_contents($url);
        preg_match_all('#<ya:created dc:date="(.*)"/>#U', $file, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        if (isset($out[0])) {
            $date = $out[0][1];
            $dt = new DateTime($date);
        }
        $random_words = array (
            'Орёл',
            'Решка'
    );
        $random_word = $random_words[array_rand($random_words)];
        function utf8_strrev($str)
        {
            preg_match_all('/./us', $str, $ar);
            return join('', array_reverse($ar[0]));
        }
        $messages_array = [
            'Тики, хелп' => "Мои команды:<br>(Пример: Тики, хелп)<br><br>Команды для обычных:<br><br>Тики, хелп<br>Тики, привет<br>Тики, как дела?<br>Тики, что делаешь?<br>Тики, какой у  меня ID?<br>Тики, какая сегодня дата?<br>Тики, сколько время?<br>Тики, монетка<br>Тики, создатель<br>Тики, рандом<br>Тики, дата регистрации<br>Тики, админы",
            'Тики, привет' => "Привет {$user_name}!",
            'Тики, как дела?' => "Нормально, {$user_name}, а у тебя как?",
            'Тики, что делаешь?' => "С тобой переписываюсь, и мне очень весело... А ты?",
            'Тики, какой у меня ID?' => "Твой ID: {$user_id}, и он самый крутой!",
            'Тики, какая сегодня дата?' => "Дата: ".date("d.m.Y"),
            'Тики, сколько время?' => "Время: ".date("H:i:s"),
            'Тики, монетка' => "Выпадает: {$random_word}",
            'Тики, создатель' => "Создатель: [id406404515|Константин]",
            'Тики, рандом' => "Рандомное число: ".rand(1, 100),
            'Тики, дата регистрации' => "Дата регистрации ВКонтакте: ".$dt->format('d.m.Y')." ".$dt->format('H:i:s'),
            'Тики, админы' => "[id406404515|Константин]",
            'Тики, переверни' =>
        ];
        foreach($messages_array as $k => $v) {
            if ($message == $k) {
                $otvet = $v;
            }
        }
        $request_params = array(
            'message' => $otvet,
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'access_token' => $token,
            'v' => '5.80'
        );

        $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);

        file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?' . $get_params);

        echo('ok');

        break;

    case 'group_join':
        $user_id = $data->object->user_id;
        $user_info = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids={$user_id}&access_token=$token&v=5.80"));
        $user_name = $user_info->response[0]->first_name;
        $request_params1 = array(
            'message' => "Привет {$user_name}! Это второй бот Тики. С этим ботом вы можете пообщаться, задавать ему вопросы, спрашивать и многое другое! Кстати, этот бот умеет переворачивать текст! Чтобы узнать команды напиши «Тики, хелп».",
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'access_token' => $token,
            'v' => '5.80'
        );

        $get_params1 = http_build_query($request_params1);

        file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?' . $get_params1);

        echo('ok');

        break;
    case 'group_leave':
        $user_id = $data->object->user_id;
        $user_info = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids={$user_id}&access_token=$token&v=5.80"));
        $user_name = $user_info->response[0]->first_name;
        $request_params2 = array(
            'message' => "Пока {$user_name}! Мы увидемся ещё? Я по тебе буду скучать(((",
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'access_token' => $token,
            'v' => '5.80'
        );

        $get_params2 = http_build_query($request_params2);

        file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?' . $get_params2);

        echo('ok');

        break;
        return false;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вся ваша реализация далеко не идеальна, рекомендую избавляться от хранения **команда - ответ** в массиве.

Но если для вас это удобно, этот вариант-велосипед должен подойти вам:

Короткий идентичный массив команд:

```
$messages_array = [
    'Тики, привет' => 'Привет',
    'Тики, переверни' => 'Введите текст!',
    'Тики, как дела?' => 'Хорошо'
];
```

Сообщение, которое приходит боту:

```
$message = 'Тики, переверни предложение';
```

Проход циклом по командам, если в `$message` есть начало команды, которая содержится в ключе массива `$messages_array`, то выполняются условия выполнения функции `utf8_strrev`:

```
foreach ($messages_array as $k => $v)
{
    if ($message == $k)
        $otvet = $v;
    elseif (preg_match("/$k/", $message) && preg_match("~$k\s(.*)~", $message, $match))
        $otvet = (!empty($match[1])) ? utf8_strrev($match[1]) : $v;
}
```

Далее используем `$otvet` по назначению для отправки пользователю.

Comment: При вводе текста "Тики, переверни" без слов, выводит "0" как это можно предотвратить или заменить "0" на "Введите текст!"?

Comment: @АминАлиев, замените `: null;` на `: 'Введите текст!';`

Comment: не помогло.....

Comment: @АминАлиев, вам сообщение приходит какое `Тики, переверни текст` или `Тики, переверни (текст)`?

Comment: Такие сообщения мне не приходят...

Я ввожу: Тики, переверни
Мне отвечает: 0

Comment: @АминАлиев, ну вы скажи формат какой со скобками, или без?

Comment: формат без скобок

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81183/discussion-between-lets-say-pie-and--).

Comment: if (preg_match("/$k/", $message) && preg_match("~$k\s(.*)~", $message, $match)) {
            $otvet = (!empty($match[1])) ? "Я думаю: " . $random_word2 : $v;
        }
Всё верно? Если да, то всё равно отвечает: 0

Comment: @АминАлиев, почему у вас `if`, если в моем ответе `elseif`?

Comment: и с elseif ответ: 0

Comment: @АминАлиев, вы массив обновили? Вот вам пример. у меня все работает, только strrev обычный [`тык`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/498ab2ba689ad093841054fe9259f11c7151004a)

Comment: Всё так, но ответ всё равно: 0

Comment: Если вы хотите знать: Это бот ВКонтакте.

Comment: @АминАлиев, зайдите в чат